# Calculating monthly reports or statistics - MVC Entity Framework LinQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using MVC (C#) and the Entity Framework. I have a sql server database with tables called Profile, Gallery, ArtWork :

PROFILE:
UserName,
FirstName,
etc...

GALLERY:
GalleryID,
**UserName**,
GalleryName,

ARTWORK:
ImageGuid,
**GalleryID**,
Description,
PublishDate,
Views,
Downloads,

I have the following relationship between the tables:

Profile->Gallery->ArtWork (Foreign keys in bold above)

What I would like to know is the most efficient way to aquire the following for the stats page:

1. The Top 10 Downloaded bits of art work of the month
2. The most Downloaded designer of the month.

Its easy enough to construct the LinQ for the above but I don't want to be hitting the database everytime a user views the stats page. There could be 30,000+ designers having 5000+ bits of artwork each, and i dont want these results being calculated everytime someone hits the stats page. I only want to hit the database daily for stat **1**, and monthly for stat **2**.

Am I best using a view for each stat in the database and hitting that all the time, or would it be best setting a timer to hit the database daily and monthly (if so how please?), or is there a better way.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the query result in the application [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx). If you do this it doesn't matter so much how you construct the query, since it will only be run once until the cached item expires.

Comment: A logical idea and very clean. Thank you for your quick response.